# How can JavaFX controllers access other services?

Tags: java, scala, javafx-2

I am using JavaFX 2 with Scala.

I have the `class Application extends javafx.application.Application` which does things like reads app configuration, etc. Then it fires up the main window.

This main window needs to be connected to a controller called `MainWindow`. I can do it with `fx:controller="com.foo.bar.MainWindow"`, however, in this case the instance of `MainWindow` is unable to access my application's configuration, etc.

One thing that came to my mind is to instantiate the `MainWindow` controller on my own inside the `Application` class and inject all dependencies, and then tell the main window view that the controller should be the instance I just created. However, I have no idea how to do this?

What's the preferred way to access data in controllers in JavaFX -- via some sort of dependency injection or something else?

**In other words,** this view FXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.Scene?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>

<BorderPane fx:controller="com.foo.bar.MainWindow" prefHeight="703.0" prefWidth="803.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
...
```

Will automatically instantiate a `com.foo.bar.MainWindow` controller for me(?):

```
...
class MainWindow {
  var app: Application = null
  ...
}
```

where I have the reference to my application, which holds information I want to access:

```
class Application extends javafx.application.Application {
  ...
  // Stuff I want to access, application also fires up the first scene.
}
```

The problem is that how can I get a reference to the main application? How can I do dependency injection or anything equivalent?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Guice is my preferred way of injecting controllers, all you need to use the following controller factory:

```
class GuiceControllerFactory implements Callback<Class<?>, Object> {

    private final Injector injector;

    public GuiceControllerFactory(Injector anInjector) {
        injector = anInjector;
    }

    @Override
    public Object call(Class<?> aClass) {
        return injector.getInstance(aClass);
    }
}
```

Set it on your FXMLLoader:

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();         
loader.setControllerFactory(controllerFactory);
```

Now Guice will create your controller. I recommend that you inject in any services your controller needs instead of passing in a reference to your application class.

Comment: Thanks for registering to post your answer! This helps a lot, but do you know how can I write that `implements Callback<Class<?>, Object>` part in Scala?

Comment: And what is `Injector`? I can't find it in the JavaFX packages.

Comment: Sorry, I barely know anything about Scala.  I'm sure java and scala generics can interop, if they don't you're going to have a hard time with javafx.

Comment: Injector is part of Guice, or in Guice 3 it is in the javax.inject package.  You will need to download Guice and add it to your classpath for the above code to compile.