# Inject dependencies to the Java fx application

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

Probably I miss somehting out, but I'm struggeling to find a solution how I can pass dependencies like an instance of my event bus and some service interfaces to my javafx application.

I got an UI-Init class which does not much more than starting the application and receiving some dependencies for the UI like an eventBus:

```
public class Frontend {

public Frontend(MBassador<EventBase> eventBus) {
    Application.launch(AppGui.class);
}
```

My AppGui class extends Application and loads an FXML:

```
public class AppGui extends Application {

private Stage primaryStage;
private GridPane rootLayout;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
    try {
        // Load root layout from fxml file.
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("RootLayout.fxml"));
        rootLayout = (GridPane) loader.load();

        // Show the scene containing the root layout.
        Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout);
        scene.setFill(null);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);

        RootLayoutController rootController = loader.getController();
        rootController.init(/*here I would like to inject my eventBus*/);

        primaryStage.show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Now, how can I pass my eventBus and other service interfaces to this controller? I've read about using DI frameworks like guice ([How can JavaFX controllers access other services?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12439172/how-can-javafx-controllers-access-other-services)) or afterburner.fx to use it. But even if I use guice for the rest of my application, somehow I need to pass the Injector instance to the JavaFX application?.

But Application.launch(AppGui.class); is static and internally creates an AppGui instance on the javafx thread, which I don't get access to. So how I can inject dependencies to my AppGui object without using static variables?

Answer (score 4):

Here is what I do:

The [`Application`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.graphics/javafx/application/Application.html) class has a couple of lifecycle callbacks, [`init()`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.graphics/javafx/application/Application.html#init()) and [`stop()`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.graphics/javafx/application/Application.html#stop()).

From [the Javadoc](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.graphics/javafx/application/Application.html#init()):

> `public void init() throws java.lang.Exception`
>
> The application initialization method. This method is called immediately after the Application class is loaded and constructed. An application may override this method to perform initialization prior to the actual starting of the application.
>
> `public void stop() throws java.lang.Exception`
>
> This method is called when the application should stop, and provides a convenient place to prepare for application exit and destroy resources.

Also from the Javadocs, the lifecycle:

> 1. Constructs an instance of the specified `Application` class
> 2. Calls the `init()` method
> 3. Calls the `start(javafx.stage.Stage)` method
> 4. Waits for the application to finish, which happens when either of the following occur:
>
>    - the application calls `Platform.exit()`
>    - the last window has been closed and the `implicitExit` attribute on `Platform` is `true`
> 5. Calls the stop() method

I start the [Inversion of Control (IoC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) container in `init()` and stop it in `stop()`. Now my `Application` class has a reference to the IoC container and can supply the first controller with its dependencies.

As a matter of fact, I let the IoC framework manage the controllers. I set them to the loaded FXML using `FXMLLoader.setController()`, instead of specifying them with `fx:controller`.

Comment: But what do you do if you have a stateful and already existent object which  you need in the fx application?

Comment: I am bypassing this problem: all initializations are done in the `init()` method. I believe it should be fairly easy to migrate the code from, e.g. the standard `main()` to `init()` - you even have access to command line options. I you cannot migrate for some reason, then this is not a suitable solution.

Comment: As @Nikos says, you should really think of the `start()` method as a replacement for the `main()` method in a "traditional" application (i.e. your `FrontEnd` class either becomes a subclass of `Application`, or is instantiated from an `Application` subclass). If you can't do that, you would have to expose your `eventBus` somewhere (e.g. as a singleton or in a singleton repository; in the latter case you can pass a key as a command line argument to launch in order to retrieve it from the repository).

Comment: @James_D Absolutely agree.

Comment: Thanks for your replies!
 That's unfortunately extactly my case. I have larger application running in the same process, having multipe components and another main swing UI, while the fx UI is only a small component which starts if desired (depending on a command line argument). I was hoping there is a way without a global repository.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a static reference to your application class before you call `launch()`. Something like:

```
public class Frontend {
    public Frontend(MBassador<EventBase> eventBus) {
        AppGui.setEventBus(eventBus);
        Application.launch(AppGui.class);
    }
}

public class AppGui extends Application {
    private static MBassador<EventBase> eventBus;
    public static void setEventBus(MBassador<EventBase> eventBus) {
        this.eventBus = eventBus;
    }

    private MBassador<EventBase> eventBus;

    @Override
    public void init() {
        if (AppGui.eventBus == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(); 
            // or however you want to handle that state
        } else {
            this.eventBus = AppGui.eventBus;
            AppGui.eventBus = null; 
        }
    }
}
```

Whether you keep and use the static reference, or you copy the static reference to a local reference is up to you and the design of your application. If you expect to instantiate more than one copy of AppGui, you may need the local reference.

No idea if this is thread safe (probably not). The advice from @Nikos and @James_D is solid and preferred... but sometimes you just need a hack. :) YMMV

Comment: There is only ever one instance of your subclass of `Application` in JavaFX. [The Javadoc](xx) says as much when it warns not to use JavaFX any further after `Application#stop` returns, at the end of the GUI’s life.

Comment: I am concerned that your use of `Frontend` to access a `static` would load the `Application` subclass on the `main` thread which *might* be a problem given that [the Javadoc](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.graphics/javafx/application/Application.html#init()) explicitly says that "launcher loads and initializes the specified Application class on the JavaFX Application Thread". I wonder if there might be some kind of problem with loading the subclass on another thread first. I am a JavaFX neophyte, so I really don't know if this is a problem or not.